# Writing secure code: a practitioner's approach?

Tags: security, mobile

I'm looking for a good book on writing secure code, with an emphasis on mobile applications. A practitioner's approach would be better than a academic discussion of the theory/algorithms/etc.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

['Writing Secure Code' by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=5957) is okay - if a tad Microsoft specific, and you could have a look at ['Developing Secure Mobile Applications for Android'](http://www.isecpartners.com/files/iSEC_Securing_Android_Apps.pdf) by ISEC

Comment: Thanks, Rory. I'll check them out. :)

Answer (score 1):

See also [Are there any coding guidelines for the Android platform that focus on security?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5968982/781723) and [Android API/development security pitfalls](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5107/971), which are nominally focused on Android -- but actually raise issues that are relevant to every mobile application platform.