# Are there any coding guidelines for the Android platform that focus on security?

Tags: android, security, code-access-security, secure-coding

Are there any good coding guidelines for the Android platform that focus on security?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to [take a look at the security design of the framework itself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html). Also,
as a more general source of security guidelines for mobile applications, you may want to look at the book "[Mobile Application Security](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/mobile/9780071633567)".

Answer (score 1):

See also [Android API/development security pitfalls](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5107/971), which discusses some pitfalls to watch out for (although the answers are more focused on design errors rather than coding guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

Another book you may want to check out: [Android Security: Attacks and Defenses](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439896461)

Also, [these coding guidelines](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=111509535) were published recently by [CERT](http://www.cert.org/):